# Synth data.prep error "treated unit among controls"

Tags: r, synth

I'm pretty inexperienced with R but as I understand it, the `Synth` package is supposed to create a synthetic projection "control group". I am trying to create a synthetic projection of what the the homicide rates in a given state would have been if that state had not abolished the death penalty - for context, I'm looking at 1996-2014 for NY, death penalty was abolished in 2007 there so I'm looking for a projection from 2007-2014. `Synth` seems to hate that I'm sticking to that state's data, it keeps asking for control data... I thought the whole point was to create a synthetic control.

Below are a few attempts. Any insight into how to set up this data.prep to give me a synthetic projection for homicide rate 2007-2014 would be appreciated. Not sure if this will make any sense out of context but here goes:

```
NewYork$STATE2 <- as.character(NewYork$STATE)
dataprep.out <-
dataprep(foo = NewYork, predictors = c("YEAR", "DEATH.PENALTY"), 
         predictors.op = "mean", dependent = "HOMICIDE", 
         unit.variable = "DEATH.PENALTY", time.variable = "YEAR",
         treatment.identifier = 0, controls.identifier = 1,
         time.predictors.prior = c(1996:2006), time.optimize.ssr = c(1996:2007),
          unit.names.variable = "STATE2", time.plot = 1996:2014)
```

> Error in dataprep(foo = NewYork, predictors = c("YEAR", "DEATH.PENALTY"),  :
>   please specify at least two control units

```
dataprep.out <- dataprep(foo = NewYork, predictors = c("YEAR", "DEATH.PENALTY"),
                         predictors.op = "mean", dependent = "HOMICIDE",
                         unit.variable = "DEATH.PENALTY", time.variable = "YEAR",
                        treatment.identifier = 0, controls.identifier = c(1,1),
                        time.predictors.prior = c(1996:2006),
                        time.optimize.ssr = c(1996:2007),
                        unit.names.variable = "STATE2",
                        time.plot = 1996:2014)
```

> Error in dataprep(foo = NewYork, predictors = c("YEAR", "DEATH.PENALTY"),  : 
>   duplicate control units in controls.identifier

```
NewYork$DEATH.PENALTY2 <- ifelse(NewYork$YEAR<2000,2,NewYork$DEATH.PENALTY)
dataprep.out<-
    dataprep(foo = NewYork, predictors = c("YEAR", "DEATH.PENALTY2"),
    predictors.op = "mean", dependent = "HOMICIDE", unit.variable = "DEATH.PENALTY2",
    time.variable = "YEAR", treatment.identifier = 0, controls.identifier = c(1,2),
    time.predictors.prior = c(1996:2006), time.optimize.ssr = c(1996:2007),
    unit.names.variable = "STATE2", time.plot = 1996:2014)
```

> Error in dataprep(foo = NewYork, predictors = c("YEAR", DEATH.PENALTY2"),  : 
>    treated unit among controls**

Comment: You need to include states that had the death penalty for the entirety of your sample. These are the controls. If you do not include counterfactual candidates, you have no identification with this method.

Comment: This makes sense. Where in the code would this go?

Comment: I think the dataset needs to be larger than NY, and it appears that the controls.identifier and treatment.identifier arguments are where you will tell the function which state is the treatment, and which are the controls. I don't have this package on my computer, but take a look at what `?dataprep` says about these arguments.